# How to change image and background color every x seconds. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

Desired outcome = change image and bg color every x seconds.

Problem I'm running into = it is not displaying every color and image. It is going from pink -> orange -> pink -> orange, skipping blue and green.

```
import * as React from 'react';

// Images
import heroPink from './hero-pink.png';
import heroBlue from './hero-blue.png';
import heroOrange from './hero-orange.png';
import heroGreen from './hero-green.png';
import logo from './oddballs_logo.svg';


const colors = [
  "#F9B199",
  "#237E95",
  "#D79446",
  "#C2C138"
];

const images = [
  heroPink,
  heroBlue,
  heroOrange,
  heroGreen
];

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setValue((v) => (v === 3 ? 0 : v + 1));
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ backgroundColor: colors[value] }}>
      <img src={images[value]}/>
    </div>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear your interval with the return statement. That means, in every un-mount the interval will clear and when this component will mount, new interval will register. It works fine for me, hope your problem will solve also.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setValue((v) => {
        return v === 4 ? 0 : v + 1;
      });
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

---

> Remember, clearing any interval events is important. Otherwise it
> occurs memory leak.

---

Here is the full example:

```
import React from "react";

const colors = ["#92c952", "#771796", "#24f355", "#d32776", "#f66b97"];

const images = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150/d32776",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/150/f66b97"
];

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setValue((v) => {
        return v === 4 ? 0 : v + 1;
      });
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ backgroundColor: colors[value] }}>
      <img src={images[value]} alt="img" style={{ border: "3px solid" }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can also simplify the state update by doing `setValue((v) => (v + 1) % 4);`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yeh, I just need to console.log v :) updating my answer.

Comment: oh `(v+1)%4` , excellent  @PatrickRoberts

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` function to achieve the behavior. Here I have used two states for color and image indexes.

```
const colors = ["#eb4034", "#ebdb34", "#34eb37"];

const images = [
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1649894158666-c10421960f13?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2071&q=50",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1648737154448-ccf0cafae1c2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585974738771-84483dd9f89f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1072&q=80"
];

export default function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(0);
  const [color, setColor] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (image === images.length - 1 && color === colors.length - 1) {
        setImage(0);
        setColor(0);
      } else {
        setImage(image + 1);
        setColor(color + 1);
      }
    }, 3000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [image, color]);

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: `${colors[color]}`, padding: "20px" }}>
      <img src={images[image]} style={{ width: "100%" }} alt="img" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also cleanup the interval unmounting phase.